# How many integer solutions are there to $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=31$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

with
a) $x_i\geq0$

b) $x_i>0$

c) $x_i \geq i(i = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)$

Now $a)$ seems simple enough to me, just use stars and bars to have $C(31+5-1, 31) = 52360$

But I'm completely stuck on b) and c), I'm not sure what do to with these constraints.

Any tips would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: Have you ever heard about stars and bars (also called sticks and stones)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the combinatorial problem of dividing 31 balls into 5 cells. In (a) the answer is what you gave. In (b) we assume that there already on ball in each cell so we have 26 balls to distribute in 5 cells so the answer is $C(26+5-1,26)=C(30,26)=27405$. In (c) the $i$th cell has already $i$ balls so we have $31-(1+2+3+4+5)=16$ balls to distribute so the answer is $C(16+5-1,16)=C(20,16)=4845$

Answer (score 2):

Transformation of variables works the best.

We defiine $y_i=x_i-i$

i.e number of solutions of

$$y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4+y_5+(1+2+3+4+5)=31$$

$$y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4+y_5=16$$ where each $y_i\ge 0$

Answer (score 0):

B and C can be similarly solved.
For example for B, subtract 1 from each variable. So same formula just substitute 31 with 26. Hope this helps.

Comment: @GetPoked234 How many solutions are there to $x_i < 6$ for $x_i \ge 0$ ? How many are there to $y_i < 6$ for $y_i > 0$?  How many solutions are there to $z_i < 5$ for $z_i \ge 0$ ?

Comment: I figured it out. Thank You However!